# Error writing to the Ajax database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress

At me in the project the table with values ​​which are deduced from a DB is formed. After I made a comparison of the 2 tables and output of these values ​​in a loop, I stopped saving to the database. I made the save in the **rel_eq** table, and the comparison made the **rel_eq** table with **rel_cat**. Help please solve this problem.

Here I compare the columns of 2 tables and output the output in a loop

```
<?php 
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_eq';
    $table_cat = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_cat';
    $eq_arr = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name JOIN $table_cat on $table_name.relcat = $table_cat.id");
?>

  <table align="center" cellpadding="10" border="1" id="user_table">
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Anonce</th>
<th>Url</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
 foreach($eq_arr as $row):
 ?> 

  <tr id="row<?php echo $row->id;?>">
  <td id="title_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->title;?></td>
  <td id="anonce_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->anonce;?></td>
  <td id="url_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->url;?></td>
  <td id="relcat_val<?php echo $row->id;?>"><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>

  <td>
   <input type='button' class="edit_button" id="edit_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="edit" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
   <input type='button' class="save_button" id="save_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="save" onclick="save_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
   <input type='button' class="delete_button" id="delete_button<?php echo $row->id;?>" value="delete" onclick="delete_row('<?php echo $row->id;?>');">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Here I write the data edited from the table into the database

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php' );
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'rel_eq';
if ( isset( $_POST['edit_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->update( $table_name, array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id'],
        'title' => $_POST['title_val'], 
        'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],
        'url' => $_POST['url_val'],
        'relcat' => $_POST['cat_val']),

    array( 'id' => $_POST['row_id'] ),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['insert_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
        'title' => $_POST['title_val'], 
        'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],
        'url' => $_POST['url_val'],
        'relcat' => $_POST['cat_val']),
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}

if ( isset( $_POST['delete_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name, array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id']),
        array( '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}
```

My ajax requests

```
function edit_row(id)
{
 var title=document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var anonce=document.getElementById("anonce_val"+id).innerHTML;
 var url=document.getElementById("url_val"+id).innerHTML;

 document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='title_text"+id+"' value='"+title+"'>";
 document.getElementById("anonce_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='anonce_text"+id+"' value='"+anonce+"'>";
 document.getElementById("url_val"+id).innerHTML="<input type='text' id='url_text"+id+"' value='"+url+"'>";

 document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="block";
}

function save_row(id)
{
 var title=document.getElementById("title_text"+id).value;
 var anonce=document.getElementById("anonce_text"+id).value;
 var url=document.getElementById("url_text"+id).value;

 jQuery.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'../wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/includes/update.php',
  data:{
   edit_row:'edit_row',
   row_id:id,
   title_val:title,
   anonce_val:anonce,
   url_val:url
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    document.getElementById("title_val"+id).innerHTML=title;
    document.getElementById("anonce_val"+id).innerHTML=anonce;
    document.getElementById("url_val"+id).innerHTML=url;
    document.getElementById("edit_button"+id).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById("save_button"+id).style.display="none";
   }
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('#row'+id+' input').css('display','none'); 
      $('#row'+id).html('<td>'+title+'</td><td>'+anonce+'</td><td>'+url+'</td><td><input type=\'button\' class=\'edit_button\' id=\'edit_button"+id+"\' value=\'edit\' onclick=\'edit_row("+id+");\'/><input type=\'button\' class=\'save_button\' id=\'save_button"+id+"\' value=\'save\' onclick=\'save_row("+id+");\'/><input type=\'button\' class=\'delete_button\' id=\'delete_button"+id+"\' value=\'delete\' onclick=\'delete_row("+id+");\'/></td>');
   });
  }
 });
}

function delete_row(id)
{
 jQuery.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'../wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/includes/update.php',
  data:{
   delete_row:'delete_row',
   row_id:id,
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response=="success")
   {
    var row=document.getElementById("row"+id);
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
   }
   jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('#row'+id).remove(); 
   });
  }
 });
}

function insert_row()
{
 var title=document.getElementById("new_title").value;
 var anonce=document.getElementById("new_anonce").value;
 var url=document.getElementById("new_url").value;

 jQuery.ajax
 ({
  type:'post',
  url:'../wp-content/plugins/related-equipment/includes/update.php',
  data:{
   insert_row:'insert_row',
   title_val:title,
   anonce_val:anonce,
   url_val:url
  },
  success:function(response) {
   if(response!="")
   {
    var id=response;
    var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
    var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
    var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='title_val"+id+"'>"+title+"</td><td id='anonce_val"+id+"'>"+anonce+"</td><td id='url_val"+id+"'>"+url+"</td><td><input type='button' class='edit_button' id='edit_button"+id+"' value='edit' onclick='edit_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='save_button' id='save_button"+id+"' value='save' onclick='save_row("+id+");'/><input type='button' class='delete_button' id='delete_button"+id+"' value='delete' onclick='delete_row("+id+");'/></td></tr>";
    document.getElementById("new_title").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_anonce").value="";
    document.getElementById("new_url").value="";
   }
  }
 });
}
```

Comment: are u using wordpress?

Comment: It's plugin for wordpress

Comment: Just at first glance, are you supplying 5 fields for the 'edit', but only specifying 4 substitutions?

Comment: "the Ajax database" is not a thing. Ajax is just a way of making HTTP requests from a browser. The fact you are using the ajax request to trigger some server-side code which interacts with a database is just a coincidence - there's no requirement for an ajax (or any other HTTP) request to do such a thing. Just a niggle but I think it helps you understand the terminology and the role of the tools you're using. Anyway there's a lot of code here. "Stopped working" isn't a very helpful explanation. Please show what debugging steps you've done and any errors or unexpected behaviour in detail

Answer (score 0):

I can't fully digest what you're saying is the 'problem' here, but it looks to me like if it isn't working, it's probably due to not specifying the 'edit' correctly.

You're specifying 4 fields plus an Update ID, so the substitution parameters should be amended as follows (assuming 'id' is an integer):

```
$wpdb->update($table_name,
array('id'=>$_POST['row_id'],'title' => $_POST['title_val'],'anonce' => $_POST['anonce_val'],'url' => $_POST['url_val'],'relcat' => $_POST['cat_val']),
array( 'id' => $_POST['row_id'] ),
array( '%d', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'), 
array( ‘%d’ ));
```

Also, in the 'delete', are you sure the 'row ID' is a String (%s)?

```
if ( isset( $_POST['delete_row'] ) ){
    $wpdb->delete( $table_name, array(
        'id'=>$_POST['row_id']),
        array( '%s') 
    );
     echo mysql_insert_id();
     exit();
}
```

The Wordpress Documentation is a good resource to use, in case I've not explained clearly what I can see:

[WordpressDB Update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/)

[WordpressDB Insert](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/)